# Formatting in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

Hi I have an Access query (below) that I'm trying to recreate in SQL Server:

```
UPDATE tblProducts SET tblProducts.ProductCode = [tblProducts].[ProductPrefix] & 
Format([tblProducts].[ProductID],"00000")
WHERE (((tblProducts.ProductCode) Is Null Or (tblProducts.ProductCode) <>[tblProducts].[ProductPrefix] & 
Format([tblProducts].[ProductID],"00000")));
```

I'm having trouble with the FORMAT function.

Comment: SQL-Server or Access?

Comment: What is the difficulty you are facing? any error messages?

Comment: Sorry, the query Ive posted is an access query, im trying to recreate it in SQL

Comment: I'm getting "Format" is not a recognized built in function name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **SQL Server 2012** and up you can use:

```
UPDATE tblProducts 
SET ProductCode = [ProductPrefix] + Format([ProductID],'00000')
WHERE ProductCode IS NULL OR ProductCode != [ProductPrefix] + Format([ProductID],'00000');
```

Another way with [STUFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) (**SQL Server (starting with 2008)**):

```
UPDATE tblProducts 
SET ProductCode = [ProductPrefix] + STUFF('00000' + CAST(ProductID as nvarchar(10)),1,LEN(ProductID),'')
WHERE ProductCode IS NULL OR 
    ProductCode != [ProductPrefix] + STUFF('00000' + CAST(ProductID as nvarchar(10)),1,LEN(ProductID),'')
```

Comment: Brilliant i was trying to use FORMAT() on SQL server 2008. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Here is one method of doing the formatting:

```
UPDATE tblProducts 
    SET ProductCode = [ProductPrefix] +
                      RIGHT('00000' + CAST(COALESCE(ProductId, 0) as VARCHAR(255)), 5)
WHERE ProductCode Is Null OR
      ProductCode <> [ProductPrefix] + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(ProductId as VARCHAR(255)), 5);
```

Actually, to prevent problems, I would phrase this as:

```
WITH toupdate AS (
      SELECT p.*,
             ([ProductPrefix] +
               RIGHT('00000' + CAST(COALESCE(ProductId, 0) as VARCHAR(255)), 5)
             ) as new_ProductCode
      FROM tblProducts p
     )
UPDATE toupdate
    SET  ProductCode = new_ProductCode
    WHERE ProductCode Is Null OR
          ProductCode <> new_ProductCode;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead of `format([tblProducts].[ProductID], "00000")`

```
right('00000'+cast([tblProducts].[ProductID] as varchar(5)),5)
```